# Signal is always caught by parent process first

Tags: command-line, process, solaris, signals, fork

Consider the following piece of code running under Solaris 11.3 (a simplified version of system(3C)):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

     pid_t pid = fork();
     pid_t w;
     int status;
     if (pid == 0) {
             execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
             perror("Failed to exec");
             exit(127);
     }
     if (pid > 0) {
             w = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
             if (w == -1) {
                     perror("Wait: ");
                     exit(1);
             }
             else if (WIFEXITED(status) > 0) {
                     printf("\nFinish code: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
             }
             else {
                     printf("\nUnexpected termination of child process.\n");
             }
     }
     if (pid == -1) {
             perror("Failed to fork");
     }

 }
```

The problem I get is that whenever the process is finished via a signal (for instance, SIGINT) the "Unexpected termination" message is never printed.

The way I see it, the whole process group receives signals from the terminal, and in this case the parent process simply terminates before waitpid(2) returns (Which happens every time, apparently).

If that is the case, I have a follow-up question. How to retrieve infromation about the signal that terminated the child process from the parent without using a signal handler? For example, I could have added another if-else block with a `WIFSIGNALED` check and a `WTERMSIG` call passing the variable `status` (In fact, I did, but  upon termination with Ctrl+C the program delivered no output whatsoever)

So what exactly and in which order is happening there?

Comment: Standard out is line (terminal) or block (file) buffered by default, so a control+c could easily cause anything buffered to be lost. Use `fprintf(stderr, ` or `warnx` or such to avoid that for diagnostic messages.

Comment: @Gilles: Do you get pinged from this?  I believe that this was an incorrect migration.  The above is first and foremost a ***Unix&Linux (specifically, Solaris)*** kernel API question, and at best secondarily a programming question.  At worst, it's on-topic both on U&L *and* SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say, “… whenever the process is finished via a signal
(for instance, SIGINT) …”, but you aren’t specific enough
to enable anybody to answer your question definitively. 
If you are sending a signal to the child process with a `kill` command,
you have an odd problem. 
But if, as I suspect (and as you suggest when you say
“the whole process group receives signals from the terminal”),
you are just typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it’s simple:

- When you type an INTR, QUIT, or SUSP character,
  the corresponding signal (SIGINT, SIGQUIT, or SIGTSTP) is sent
  simultaneously to all processes in the terminal process group.

  - OK, *strictly* speaking, it’s not *simultaneous*. 
    It happens in a loop in the terminal driver
    (specifically, I believe, the “line discipline” handler), in the kernel. 
    No user process execution can occur before this loop completes.
- You say “… the parent process simply terminates
  before waitpid(2) returns (… every time, apparently).” 
  Technically this is true. 
  As described above, all processes in the process group
  (including your parent and child processes) receive the signal
  (essentially) simultaneously. 
  Since the parent is not handling the signal, itself,
  it terminates before it can possibly do any processing
  triggered by the child’s receipt of the signal.
- You say “Signal is always caught by parent process first”. 
  No; see above. 
  And the processes terminate in an unspecified order —
  this may be the order in which they appear in the process table
  (which is indeterminate),
  or determined by some subtle (and, perhaps, undocumented) aspect
  of the scheduler’s algorithm.

Related U&L questions:

- [What is the purpose of abstractions, session, session leader
  and process groups?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82844/80216#82949)
- [What are the responsibilities of each Pseudo-Terminal (PTY) component
  (software, master side, slave side)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117981/80216#120071)

Answer (score 1):

Does it work ok if you send signals via a "kill" from another tty?  I tried this on linux.  Seems the same behavior.

I think you're right if that shell control signals are passed to the process group....and you have a race.    You need in the parent to catch and delay them.

What I've done is do "./prog cat"

Doing a kill -SIGINT 
works fine.

Doing a control-C prints nothing.

Doing a setsid() in front has the parent terminate, but the child keep running.